# Proof that a continuous function is zero

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:[0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that $\int^1_0 f(x)x^ndx=0$ $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$. Show that $f \equiv 0$ in [0, 1].

I need help.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

- Using the linearity of the integral and with the hypothesis we get

$$\int_0^1 f(x)p(x)dx=0$$
for every polynomial $p$

- Using the [Stone–Weierstrass theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) we get
  $$\int_0^1f^2(x)dx=0$$
  and we conclude the desired result.