# $ \int_a^bx^nf(x)\mathrm{d}x=0,\ n=0,1,2,\cdots. $ Prove that $f=0$.

Tags: polynomials, weierstrass-approximation

> $f$ is a continuous function on $[a,b]$. If
> $$
> \int_a^bx^nf(x)\mathrm{d}x=0,\ n=0,1,2,\cdots.
> $$
> Prove that $f(x)=0$.
> A further problem is we only have
> $$
> \int_a^bx^nf(x)\mathrm{d}x=0,\ n=1,2,\cdots.
> $$
> Prove the same result.

I tried to use a polynomial to approach $f(x)$, i.e.
$$
\forall \epsilon>0, \exists  P(x), \forall x\in[a,b],\ |f(x)-P(x)|\leq\epsilon.
$$
Therefore,
$$
\int_a^bx^n(P(x)-\epsilon)\mathrm{d}x\leq\int_a^bx^nf(x)\mathrm{d}x\leq \int_a^bx^n(P(x)+\epsilon)\mathrm{d}x.
$$
But I do not know how to go on. It seems we only need to see the coefficient of the first term, but I cannot write a clear proof of that.
Appreciate any help!

Comment: One approach: if you approximate $f(x)$ with a polynomial $f(x) \sim a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + \ldots$ then $0 = \sum \int a_n x^n f(x) \sim \int f(x)^2$. You would need to make this a bit more precise.

Comment: see also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2380609/use-weierstrass-approximation-to-prove-that-fx-0-with-questions-on-the-deta https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1048287/proof-that-a-continuous-function-is-zero https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3073455/suppose-f-is-a-lebesgue-integrable-function-on0-1-which-satisfies-int-x?noredirect=1&lq=1 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2598875/int-pi-pi-xnfx-0-for-all-non-negative-integer-n-then-f-will-be?noredirect=1&lq=1 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1287313/showing-a-function-identically-zero?noredirect=1&lq=1